# Make a unix alias with python script

Tags: python, bash, unix

I want to make a python script(.py) make a UNIX alias that can be accesed after the program has ran. How can i do this?

I have tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

os.system('alias cdd="cd ~/Desktop/"')
```

Comment: You should open the right file for the shell the user is using, and then append the alias to it

Comment: Yes, write it to the .bashrc ?

Comment: Can you give me an explanation on how i could do this?

Comment: You are only defining the alias in the shell that `os.system` spawns, which immediately exits. You *must* do this from a shell script that is sourced (not executed), rather than a Python (or Perl, or Ruby, or any other language) script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of an `alias` command is the shell it is run in.  When that shell exits and a new one starts, it will not have the alias defined.

The way persistent customization is provided to shells is with shell scripts that are run when the shell first starts up.  For example, bash will run either or both of `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` depending on how it is invoked and other local configuration.  Refer to the documentation for the shell you're interested in interacting with for all of the specific details of how it handles this.

If you want persistent configuration changes to a shell, you need to modify the shell's startup scripts.

`os.system` runs a shell and tells the shell to run the command you supplied.  Then the shell exits.  So running an `alias` command with `os.system` can basically accomplish nothing useful.

Here's an example of how you might adjust your bash configuration to define an alias persistently:

```
with open(expanduser("~/.bashrc"), "at") as bashrc:
    bashrc.write(
        "\n"
        "# Added by myprogram on somedate\n"
        "alias cdd='cd ~/Desktop/'\n"
    )
```

Comment: `bash` itself will never run both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, but `.bash_profile` is commonly configured to explicitly source `.bashrc`.

Comment: I dont have a bashrc file or a bash_profile file on my computer. what can i do then?

Comment: Make one.  Read the bash documentation about these files.